# How to best organize files

Tags: file, organization

Often, when doing a process or storing files I typically try to work with a workflow, or system.

For instance, when I download a file, I sort it within a folder Programming/Downloads/Templates/ or Libraries, etc., and when I start a project I create a new folder for it within a workspace folder.

This works fine, unless I need slightly more control, and when I go back, I typically have old projects within a different folder from a few years back, but typically with the same structure (and cannot find things before I setup a structure, or saved things in crazy places, like utilities for school in the school, not the programming folder.)

How do you sort files or projects?

Furthermore, after a certain point of time how/where do you backup / archive them?

Comment: Isn't this a superuser question?

Comment: It seems to be a programming question about organizing files. Seems legitimate to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what's to answer here?

i divide to Platforms, then to projects.. nothing special...

Comment: Anything really.
That's typically what I do, but I often mix php with javascript and html pages for quick utilities (same with cgi). It doesn't make sense to package a simple php application or two in a file.

However, more of the question I'm asking is do you have a typical way to store files within a program or within platforms.

Sometimes, though, I don't think using platforms, then projects is enough. What about old and obsolete projects/apps that just junk up the directory (unless you need them later)?

Do you archive them, move them, leave them etc?